# Why join and group by affects the amount of data shuffle in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Im using spark and Im seeing that when a query have a lot of join operations and group by spark needs to do a lot of shuffle operations. I was looking to find information why this happen but Im not finding nothing in concrete. Can you give a help to understaning this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spark shuffles is simply moving around data in the cluster. So ever transformation that require data that is not present locally in the partition would perform a shuffle. Looking at join, each partition needs to go through the entire joined df in order to  complete the operation so a shuffle is done which basically moves the joined df to every active partition. Same thing will happen with group by key where all the same keys needs to end up in the same partition so the shuffle moves them there. As you can see this is not very good performance wise so you should try and avoid it if possible.

Comment: I thanks for your answer. I just not understand what you mean by partition. For exmaple "ever transformation that require data that is not present locally in th epartition would..". Can you explain?

Comment: Partitions are the actual works in the cluster. each job is divided between the partitions.You can think of it as threads, just across the cluster. You can have a spark job to be spreaded across 20 partitions in a 3 nodes cluster. This parallel's the work in each node (JVM) so the total of partitions/workers are 20 in total.  "By default, Spark creates one partition for each block of the file (blocks being 64MB by default in HDFS), but you can also ask for a higher number of partitions by passing a larger value."

Answer (score 5):

In simpler words:

1. The data is spread across.

   - Spark runs on top of a distributed file system, like HDFS. Since it's a distributed file system, the data is spread across the cluster.
   - An RDD is an abstraction for a distributed dataset, thus data that constitutes an RDD is spread across the cluster.
2. Sometimes, data has to be moved around.

   - Whenever you come across an operation for which the rows that have the same key will need to be together, be worried.
   - Since it is a distributed file system, rows with the same key will need to travel across the cluster (*shuffled*) to be together. This is the case, for example, when you want to combine two RDDs by the key (`join`), or when you want to collect all the values for a key together and perform an operation on them (`groupByKey`).
3. The amount of data that needs to travel may not always be a lot. For your specific cases:

   - for joins, if the RDDs are [co-partitioned](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html), or if we have made sure that rows with the same keys sit together, there won't be *any* shuffle during the join!
   - You can reduce the amount of the data shuffled in a `groupByKey` operation by shifting to [`reduceByKey`](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html). However, this is no silver bullet, there are cases where you may want to stay with `groupByKey`.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. So when you say combine two rdds by the key that is what happens in the join, spark automatically creates more than one RDD? For example if we execute a query in spark sql over hdfs or hive with a join and group by spark will create more than 1 rdd from the sql statement in the spark sql method?